# Calling another job

Tags: activebatch

I am trying to call a job from another job and it is giving me 'TriggerJob Run Job': The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. error.

TriggerJob Run Job

Job Scheduler ActiveBatch9
ActiveBatchCredentials /ActiveBatchTask
ActiveBatch Plan/Job TestJobs/test3
Variables FileNameFullPath = %{File}
Wait Completion  True

Comment: We're having the same problem, near as I can tell from ASCI's KB the problem is with the execution agent communicating back to the scheduler. There a certificate problem on the scheduler.

https://www.advsyscon.com/en-us/myasci/kb-view?articleid=20180320131153&searchPhrase=relationship